# how to get value outside jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a on click function to get the id of a,and I want to alert it.
The following code is not working showing null, why? thanks

```
var projectId=null;

$('body').on('click', '#list a', function(){
                  projectId=this.id; //id should = 30
                  alert(projectId);  //here display 30
});

alert(projectId); //here display null
```

---

what i really want to do is :
a.js I have sth like, when I click "a" it redirect to another page which need to render by my projectId:href='/projectDetail' this page call b.js

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'http://xxx',
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        var projectList="<ul style='list-style:none;'>"

                        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {

                                projectList += "<li><div id='listall'><a 
                           id='"+data.data[i].projectId+"' 
                             href='/projectDetail'>"+ 
                                  "<img class='back' src='/img/Homepage_ProjectFrame.png'></li>"
                                 }
                              var projectList="<ul>"
                             });

var projectId=null;

 $(document).on('click', '#listall a', function (){
            event.preventDefault();
             projectId=this.id;
             alert(projectId);
  });  

 alert(projectId);
```

b.js I have:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://xxx?projectId='+projectId
            dataType:'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data.data);
                $(".photoprojectD").attr("src",data.data.projectPhotoUrl);
                $(".dlocation p").html(data.data.countryName);
                $(".dcategory p").html(data.data.categoryName);
 });
```

So i need projectId from a.js to render dynamic information
Do you have any good ideas?
Thanks a lot for your guys helping

Comment: The last line runs as soon as the page loads. At which point `projectId` is still `null`

Comment: It's because the `alert()` runs when the document loads. The element has not been (and cannot be) clicked at that point, so the value is null.

Comment: The important question is: *how* and *when* do you want to actually use that value? The code you posted doesn't actually try to do anything useful. If you `alert()` the value in a second click handler, it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean, "use it in another js file"? All scripts that are loaded by an HTML document are combined into a single big script, basically. Your other js file can *already* use that value.

Comment: I have a.js and b.js if id is inside click function I cannot get the value from b.js unless  set it as Global variable. the problem is if i set it as global variable, i am not able to get the actual value @ChrisG

Comment: Did you not read my entire comment? I told you that you can already use the value in another script. You might want to include the 2nd script after this one though. To be crystal clear: declaring a `var` outside a function means it can *already* be read and changed by every function, no matter which js file that function is in.

Comment: yes, I already declared it outside a function as null and changed the value inside click function to 30 , but then outside the function I still get null, how should I get correct value 30 outside function?

Comment: Can you show the HTML for your links? Because if you don't intercept the click, the page will refresh, resetting all JS variables in the process. Try adding `return false;` to the bottom of your click handler. https://plnkr.co/edit/eFnIC1ETJfsT84M5pjM8?p=preview

Comment: @casey see my answer. Trace your code (set breakpoints if needed) - when are you accessing this value from your other file? After the link is clicked, or before? If before, it will never work, you have to wait for the user to click. And make sure your hyperlinks don't cause the page to reload / redirect in the meantime. And make sure your second file is not re-declaring another "projectId" variable with narrower scope and then trying to use _that_.

Comment: please see my update, thanks @ADyson

Comment: please see my update, thanks@ChrisG

Comment: _"when I click "a" it redirect to another page which need to render by my projectId:"_ Javascript values don't persist from one page refresh to another. The web is **stateless**. You need to understand this key concept. Whenever you refresh your browser you destroy _everything_ related to that page that was in the browser's memory, and start again like it never existed before. This includes the given value of any script variable. It all gets reset.

Comment: If you want to pass values from one page to another (or from one refresh of the same page to the next refresh of the page) you either post it back to the server and store it something persistent or semi-persistent like a database or user session, and retrieve it to include in the new page; or you put the value on the querystring of the new URL and read it from there using JavaScript directly.

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot, but finally i stored this value inside cookie

Comment: oh yes that's another way you can persist values...forgot about that one. But clearly you got the idea, glad you were able to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second `alert(projectId);` outside the "click" event handler runs as soon as the page loads. Inevitably this is *before* your "click" handler can possibly be executed, because the user has likely not had time to click on it, and even if they had time, there's no guarantee that they will. Therefore the variable `projectId` is not populated when that code executes.

You can certainly use `projectId` outside your "click" event, but you have to wait until after at least one "click" event has happened before you can expect it to have a value.

There's also danger that your hyperlinks are causing the page to postback before any of this ever happens. Since you're using jQuery you can prevent this very easily:

```
$('body').on('click', '#list a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default hyperlink redirect/reload behaviour
  projectId=this.id; //id should = 30
  alert(projectId);  //here display 30
});
```

Lastly, ensure that this other place you want to use the value is not doing anything silly like declaring another "projectId" variable with narrower scope and then trying to use *that*. For example, this will **not** work as you wish:

```
var projectId = null;

$('body').on('click', '#list a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default hyperlink redirect/reload behaviour
  projectId=this.id; //id should = 30
  alert(projectId);  //here display 30
  exampleFunc(); //call the function below
});

function exampleFunc() {
  var projectId = null; //oops, another "projectId" with narrower scope (within this function) will take precedence here
  alert(projectId); //will be null
});
```

Whereas this **will**:

```
var projectId = null;

$('body').on('click', '#list a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent default hyperlink redirect/reload behaviour
  projectId=this.id; //id should = 30
  alert(projectId);  //here display 30
  exampleFunc(); //call the function below
});
```

```js
function exampleFunc() {
  alert(projectId); //will be 30
}
```